# Using Tcl to set a verilog net value pre synthesis

Tags: tcl, verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, vivado

I have the following value defined in my main.sv that only needs to be set once:

```
logic [31:0] random_number;
```

I don't want to waste resources randomizing this value in synthesized HDL so it occurred to me that I might be able to do so in a Tcl script. My goals are to either:

1. Use a Tcl script to rewrite the HDL file with the value initialized as such:

   `logic [31:0] random_number = 32'd1057;`
2. Use a Tcl script to set the value to the net in a pre-hook.

Unfortunately, Im unsure how to use tcl do any of these things. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to clarify if you want your design to have a hard coded random value, or are you looking to test your design with a random value. In that case, you need to write a testbench to simulate it.

Comment: Sorry for the ambuguity. Indeed I want the design to have a hard coded random value that is different for each synthesis.

Comment: If that is the case, your build flow should generate a new verilog file that will be `\`included`'d into the design in order to set or define that random number.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use a parameter for your random value and assign it in your TCL script?

Comment: The value will change during runtime.

Comment: If the value will change during runtime I do not understand how you could possibly handle this in the TCL synthesis script. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

If the wire is to be drived by a constant value, no resources are wasted, no matter how that value was calculated. The synthesizer will calculate it and assign to your wire. From the electronic point of view, your logic variable will have bits tied to VCC and bits tied to GND. That's all.

So, just use something like this:

```
wire [31:0] random_number = $random;
```